# ERROR: CMake '3.19.0' or higher was not found in SDK, PATH, or by cmake.dir property

Tags: android-studio, cmake

I have done some searching and found that I should install CMake in SDK manager but the 3.19+ version does not show here as shown in the picture below.

[NoCmake3.19](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZsKFn.png)

Is there anything that has to be done in order to have CMake 3.19?

Edit:

- The android studio current version is 4.2.2
- This happen when I want to try [google/filament](https://github.com/google/filament) samples in android

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can manually download the newest cmake version (https://cmake.org/download/) and specify in gradle to use it: https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/install-ndk

Answer (score 2):

1. Follow the instructions here to download and add CMake to your path: https://tudat.tudelft.nl/installation/setupDevMacOs.html
2. Add `cmake.dir=/usr/local` into your `local.properties`
3. Rebuild your Android app

Comment: Got this : 
CXX1301] Could not get version from cmake.dir path '/usr/local'.

Answer (score 2):

If u need a specific version (for me I needed 3.18.1) you can download from [here](https://cmake.org/files/)

Answer (score 1):

Add `cmake.dir=/usr/local` into your `local.properties`. AndroidStudio add `/bin`to execute cmake.

Answer (score 0):

Leaving this here for future reference. thanks.

```
sudo JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64 ./sdkmanager "cmake;3.xx.x"
```